# How do get JQuery to work when I am using AngularJS partials?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the below code. However, my JQuery wont run when the #id and .classes it is looking for are in partials when viewing this static page. How do I get it to work?

```
 <body ng-app>  

    <h2>JQuery wont run if code it is looking for is in a Partial</h2>  
    <div ng-include="'_includes/partials/menu.html'" ></div>  

    <br />

    <h2>JQuery will work if the code it is looking for is here on the page (DOM)</h2>
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>About</a></li>
                    <li><a>Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="_includes/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_includes/scripts/custom.js"></script> 

</body>
```

Comment: I dont see any javascript... Maybe thats the problem, or you didnt share. Anyways, angular has jquery lite, and there is no need to use jquery with what u want

Comment: Most probably you run your jquery before `menu.html` is being loaded. Provide please your js code.

Comment: I don't have any JS code as I am just using it to template and render a section of HTML that is partials. .

Comment: Have a look at the angular ui stuff. Specifically the [bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) bit. Essentially the normal bootstrap js registers all its handlers on page load. Meaning it cant find anything when angular does its dynamic DOM manipulation. So you have to wrap things in directives which the angular ui stuff does.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to try to find html elements and modify them in an AngularJS app as you would normally do in a JQuery enabled html. Instead, try to implement whatever you are thinking of only using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you want to use ng-directives instead jQuery calls.